# Why is my transposition table so slow? (4x slowdown)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, cython, game-engine, chess

So I am using a transposition table (TT) to try and speed up an alphabeta minimax algorithm for some board game. But in my surprise, when I turn off the transposition table I get 4x speedup! Transposition tables are supposed to speed things up right?

So one thing I noticed is that only 10% of the time do I get a cache-hit. Not the greatest, but I shouldn't need 75% in order for the TT to be useful.

So, the idea is that the TT is a very fast cache lookup. I am using the 2Big replacement scheme. The TT stores lower- and upper-bounds, the search depth, the move and the amount of effort (size) needed to calculate the best response. `LockEntry` is just an alias for `unsigned long long`.

My code is below:

```
ctypedef struct CacheEntry:
    LockEntry lock
    minimax_score lower_bound
    minimax_score upper_bound
    int depth
    Move move
    long long size

ctypedef struct BigEntry:
    CacheEntry small
    CacheEntry large  

cdef void set_entry(CacheEntry entry):
    """set an entry into the cache"""
    global cache
    cdef int key
    key = entry.lock % PRIME
    if entry.size > cache[key].large.size or entry.lock == cache[key].large.lock:
        cache[key].large = entry
    else:
        cache[key].small = entry
    return

cdef int get_entry(CacheEntry *entry, LockEntry lock):
    """retrieve an entry from cache"""
    global cache
    global cache_queries
    global large_hits
    global small_hits
    cdef int key
    cache_queries += 1
    key = lock % PRIME
    if cache[key].large.lock == lock:
        large_hits += 1
        entry[0] = cache[key].large
        return 1 #success
    elif cache[key].small.lock == lock:
        small_hits += 1
        entry[0] = cache[key].small
        return 1 #success
    return 0 #failure
```

The `set_entry` function takes a struct CacheEntry type and puts it into the TT (uncreatively called `cache`), while the `get_entry` function takes a pointer to a `CacheEntry` and updates the value for it (I've tried returning the CacheEntry, but no difference in speed occurs.). It also returns a `1` for a successful cache-hit, and `0` for unsuccessful.

So, basically, I am out of ideas on how to use this properly. I am surprised it is slow, and when compiled with `-a` it is all `white`, so it seems that I am cythoning the code properly.

Help appreciated.

Comment: For example, is there some crazy overhead with using an array of structs rather than an array of arrays that I don't know of?

Would using an array of unsigned long long instead of an array of `BigEntry`?